# Wordpress on Azure 404 error on installation step 2

Tags: wordpress, azure, nginx

I'm installing a Wordpress site on an Azure WebApp. I have Wordpress on /home/site/wwwroot directory and when I access the web app url the installation begins. I can select the language, then I enter the DB information and when I click "Submit" I get a "404 Not Found" error from NGINX.

I have been troubleshooting and found this on th NGINX Error Log:

> 2021/09/13 17:58:36 [error] 71#71: *91 open() "/html/50x.html" failed
> (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.16.7.1, server:
> example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", u pstream:
> "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "athoz-sales.azurewebsites.net"
> 2021/09/13 17:58:36 [error] 71#71: *93 open()
> "/home/site/wwwroot/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or
> directory), client: 172.16.7.1, server: example.com, request: "GE T
> /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "athoz-sales.azurewebsites.net",
> referrer: "https://athoz-sales.azurewebsites.net/"

Can you please help me how to troubleshoot this problem and continue with the Wordpress Site installation.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: negative @HansAraya, gave up in the end and opted out for a traditional php web hosting

Comment: agh.. classic azure.. all right, thanks for replying